# Check if an certain element appears twice in a list - Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

Without importing another function check if a list contains two of the same element

F.E
list = [3,4,5,3] 
since 3 appears twice in the list return True

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You can convert to `set` and check the resulting length:

```
len(set(data)) < len(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check if the element occurs exactly twice, you could do this:

```
l = [3,4,5,3]
if 2 in set([l.count(n) for n in l]):
    print('True')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to solve this problem.

Solution 1: Use set()

```
if len(set(<your_list>))<len(<your_list>):
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Solution 2 : Use hash dictionary

```
def check_list(lst):
   hash_dict={}
   for elem in lst:
     if elem not in hash_dict:
        hash_dict[elem]=1
     else:
        return True
    return False
```

In the above solution, we add the elements in the hash dict and constantly check if it exists there, if it does then we return True. If the list has no duplicate or more than 2 elements then it will just return false.

Solution 3 : We can also use counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter
new_dict=Counter(<your list>)
return True if 2 in new_dict.values() else False
```